# Can I use this Audio Bonnet with Compute Module 4 I/O?

Tags: audio, i2s

I'm building a project that I'd like to eventually sell in small batches as a commercial product. The RPI  Compute Module 4 I/O (CM4IO) has most of what I'd need, but one extra thing I need is the ability to connect a 3.5mm audio jack to use it with headphones or speakers. Adafruit has something, but I'm not too sure if it's compatible:

https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-i2s-audio-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi-ada4037

Comment: Welcome.  I've modified your question to make it meet our [restrictions on shopping questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (see *Asking for specific purchasing recommendations*).

Comment: Does the CM4 have a compatible header?  I thought it had a different pin arrangement. https://github.com/atctwo/pinout/blob/main/screenshot.png

Comment: I was looking at this image: https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Raspberry%20Pi/MFG_SC0326.jpg Where there is pretty clearly a 40-pin header (and very near it, a "Raspberry Pi HAT" label).  The 100 pin CM header is (based on a quick search & skim) on the bottom.  That said, I thought the CM's were all PCIe based but that pic does not look like it has any such interface.

Comment: Okay, confirmation of that here: https://pi4j.com/1.3/pins/rpi-cm4.html Also, the "IO" version is quite a bit bigger than the plain CM4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product description there does say *"works with any and all Raspberry Pi computers with a 2x20 connector"*, which covers all boards except the original 1B (= a 2x13 breakout).

The 40-pin headers are intended to be compatible across all models, and while I do not have a CM4 board, it looks to have one near the "Raspberry Pi HAT" label, so this should be fine.

This is confirmed in the brief description here: https://pi4j.com/1.3/pins/rpi-cm4.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton. 